# Time complexity of T(n) = T(n - 1) + (n - 1)^2

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I am wondering what is the time complexity of this recurrence relation.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it can answered fairly easily by the OP provided that he/she does some research in google or in a textbook associated with this stuff.

Comment: Fair enough, I suppose. May you provide some sources, because I have been googling the answer for this recurrence relation but have failed to find a satisfying answer.

Comment: For instance, you could check this video, in which as it seems explains more than you need: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zVeNqLg2uUc

Comment: As general term for your google search you could use: solving Recurrence relation. You would find many valuable sources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry if I'm writing with images, but I needed to include some math:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: First, it's no problem if you use images. Second, thanks it was very helpful and cleared a lot of things up.

Answer (score 2):

T(n) = T(n-1) + f(n)

Means

T(n) = T(0) + Sum_from_i=1_to_n_of( f(i) )

In your case, that's:

T(n) = T(0) + 0<sup>2</sup> + 1<sup>2</sup> + 2<sup>2</sup> ... (n-1)<sup>2</sup>

If you don't know immediately from discrete calculus that the sum comes out to O(n<sup>3</sup>), you can notice that there are n terms, with the largest being (n-1)<sup>2</sup>, and there more than (n/3) terms that are  >= (n/2)<sup>2</sup>.